# Java Spring Boot Security - Authorization returns 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have configured a custom `OncePerRequestFilter` that grants a spring authority for authorization

```
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public JwtAuthenticationFilter(JwtService jwtService, UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.jwtService = jwtService;
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            @NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
            @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
            @NonNull FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwt;
        final String username;
        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }
        jwt = authHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtService.extractUsername(jwt);
        if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (jwtService.isTokenValid(jwt, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        userDetails,
                        null,
                        userDetails.getAuthorities()
                );
                authToken.setDetails(
                        new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
                );
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

This is my Spring Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {
    private final AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;
    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Autowired
    public SecurityConfig(AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider, JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthFilter) {
        this.authenticationProvider = authenticationProvider;
        this.jwtAuthFilter = jwtAuthFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**")        //White list for not using token
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)         //Session creation describing :: STATELESS - create session for each request
                .and()
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);     //Run custom filters before the standard filter logic

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }
}
```

And this is a method for authorization:

```
public AuthenticationResponse authenticate(AuthenticationRequest request) throws NotFoundException {
        this.authenticationManager.authenticate(
            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    request.getUsername(),
                    request.getPassword()
            )
        );
        var user = userDao.getUser(request.getUsername());
        var jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(
                UserDetailsImplementation.build(user)
        );

        return new AuthenticationResponse(jwtToken);
    }
```

What have I missed in my configuration? What did I miss in my configuration that I can't authorize the user?
There is still a method for registration, but it works fine and returns the token to me.

I have debugged code and found out that the problem is that the method execution stops after the `authenticate` is called. Therefore, the method call from `userDao` does not occur.

Comment: the tutorial you are using is outdated https://github.com/Tandolf/spring-security-jwt-demo

Comment: Tutorial, I've been using was published 3 month ago. It was published 3 month ago to describe Spring Boot Security configuration.
But thanks for the URL

Comment: I’m saying its outdated, read the spring security jwt docs and you’ll see why. what you do with that information is up to you. If you choose to not listen then that is also up to you. You are the one asking for help not me. Good luck! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JFI: an error was caused by the UserDetailsImplementation class, which implements a UserDetails intrface. An overriding for the isEnabled() method had returned wrong (reverted value) which throws "User is disabled" exception.
After the fixing this method, everything started to work.